# Vim Ресурсы По Изучению

Tags: vim

Вчера открыл для себя Vim. Хочу попробовать его в качестве IDE (Java, Python, PHP), но сомневаюсь в ссылках, которые нахожу.

Какие ресурсы использовади Вы, чтобы выучить Vim досконально?

Хотелось бы, чтобы описывалось все: как ставить темы, плагины, какие ставить лучше, и т.д.

Comment: Есть. Читайте грамотные ресурсы. A Byte of Vim Book. Скачать можно здесь. Или если ссылка вдруг не сработает, то загуглите название и скачайте в другом месте http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/vim/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

если вчера открыли, то до «досконального знания» вам ещё не один год изучать эту программу. а чтобы начать пользоваться, пройдите «быстрый курс»:

```
$ vimtutor ru
```

следующий шаг: освоение пользованием встроенной справкой. для этого запустите программу, введите `:help` и нажмите <kbd>enter</kbd>.

и, конечно, никаких «тем, плагинов», пока хоть немножко не освоитесь.