# Как выполнить commit

Tags: git

1)в директории создаю файл text.txt и прописываю в нем `123`

2)открываю git bash и прописываю

```
git init
git add text.txt
git commit
```

3)дальше появляется вот такое окно и я прописываю свой комментарий[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вопрос - что дальше нужно сделать чтобы закончить commit? если я закрою окно - коммит не выполнится. Esc тоже ничего не делает.

я знаю что можно делать через `git commit -m`, но я хочу понять как это сделать первым способом

Comment: `Esc` + напишите `:wq`, должно сработать.

Comment: Скорее всего по стандарту стоит vi, но Вы можете изменить его на, допустим, Sublime

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508285/178576

Answer (score 1):

При попытке писать коммит, вы попадаете в эмулятор `vi`, пользуйтесь горячими клавишами `vi` или `vim`.